# Inconsistent Encoding Configuration for Logging Handlers in Python Using logging.config.fileConfig

Tags: python, logging, encoding

I specified in logging.conf:

```
[handler_file_handler]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=file_formatter
args=("log/script.log","D",30,"utf-8")
```

But when I checked it using logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf"):

```
# root_logger = logging.getLogger()
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
# Iterate through logger's handlers
for handler in logger.handlers:
    if hasattr(handler, 'encoding'):
        print(f"Handler {handler} encoding: {handler.encoding}")
```

I found that the result was different:

```
Handler <TimedRotatingFileHandler D:\scripts\log\script.log (INFO)> encoding: None
```

This causes the Chinese in my log file to be unrecognizable:

```
2023-11-08 18:00:46 crop_growth_logger [D:\scripts\test.py line:52] WARNING ������־
2023-11-08 18:00:46 crop_growth_logger [D:\scripts\test.py line:53] ERROR ������־
2023-11-08 18:00:46 crop_growth_logger [D:\scripts\test.py line:54] CRITICAL ������־
```

**Python 3.8.17 **

1. Using FileHandler in config file seems to work, if I use "a" mode, it causes my log file to get bigger and bigger, if I use "w", I use this logger in different scripts, and every time I load it, it clears the log generated by other scripts.
2. or write the logger directly in the script, but that's not clean enough either

**What is the cause of this problem? Is there a perfect solution?**

Comment: The `FileHandler` class takes the following arguments `(filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False, errors=None)` but the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` class takes `(filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None, errors=None)` arguments. Both classes have encoding but in different locations. Please, try to match the arguments order according to the [Python logging handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) documentation.